# Accompanied with or by?

Tags: prepositions, difference, word-difference

Can "accompanied" be followed by preposition with?
I've only heard about accompanied by. But I want to know If there is any context in which we should use accompanied with.

> My last year was accompanied by hardships, struggles, and ups and downs.
>
> My last year was accompanied with hardships, struggles, and ups and downs.

Comment: _"Accompanied by"_ is almost a set expression. _"Accompanied with"_ will be understood; it's not incorrect, and does not differ in meaning from the usual _"accompanied by",_ but _by_ is the most commonly used preposition. There are no contexts in which one or the other is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

***[Accompanied "by" something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/accompanied+by)***  is the idiomatic usage:

> - with something extra to go along with something else; with something to complement something else.
>
>   - *Dessert was accompanied by a fine white wine.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.)

As shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accompanied%20by%2Caccompanied%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccompanied%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccompanied%20with%3B%2Cc0)"accompanied with" used to be a common expression, but it is rarely used now.

Answer (score 3):

As the following [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accompanied+with%2Caccompanied+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccompanied%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccompanied%20by%3B%2Cc0) shows, "accompanied with" has fallen out of favour over the last 200 years:

[image]

I don't know why. "Fillet steak accompanied with French fries" sounds good to me.

Comment: A cautionary note on the ngram: it analyzes only _text published in books._ That it is not an accurate guide to real usage is exemplified by the following [**ngram;**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wanna+go%2Cwant+to+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwanna%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwant%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0) in America today, the verb _wanna_ is at least as commonly used as _want to._

Answer (score 0):

Usage of ***by*** in your context has a meaning of **near or at the side of someone**:

> A small child stood sullenly **by** her side.
>
> He wanted to keep her close **by** him always.
>
> The policewoman walked **by** (= past) them without saying a word.

Usage of ***with*** in your context has a meaning of **having or including something**:

> A tall woman **with** dark hair
>
> Two coffees please, one **with** milk and one without.
>
> We're an international company **with** offices in Paris, New York, and Sydney.
>
> He woke up **with** a terrible headache.

Now lets have a look at ***accompanied***:

..to go with someone or to be provided or exist at the same time as something:

> The course books are **accompanied by** four CDs.
>
> Depression is almost always **accompanied by** insomnia.
>
> The salmon was **accompanied by** (= served with) a fresh green salad.

see? Almost in every situation it is used with **by** to express the feeling of **near or at the side of someone**.

So if you use ***with***, it will give the impression of "**not necessarily but still accompanied**" by having the meaning "**having or including something**" and if you use ***by*** instead, it will give the impression of "**someone is intended to be accompanied**".

resource: Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: Is this a great question based on research? The ways of the site is really  surprising.Which question is highlighted or upvoted  or put on hold or closed is a mystery.

Comment: How do you define a good question/answer? Some questions/answers are just shared with many that thinks in the same way and that is the reason why they get too many upvotes. Most of the really good questions/answers however are shared between only a small percentage of people that are really into it. So it is a total mystery how people reacts to something very common and something rarely seen. To be able to create questions that gets many upvotes you might wanna check https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask  and also https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The site does not help much.It  is just  like a box office release.It may go  either way. hit or flop